# Вертикальное выравнивание

Tags: html, css

Нужно выровнять текст по средине. Нужно что бы он всегда был по средине, на всех разрешениях. Как посоветуете сделать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="rent-of-dedicated-server-backups-list col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="left-side backups-list-3"><img src="img/baseico-ico.png"></div>
                    <div class="text text-left"><span>Восстановление данных</span></div>
                    <div class="text text-left">Вы сможете быстро восстанавливать данные</div>
            </div>
```

SASS

```
.rent-of-dedicated-server-backups-list{
                        padding: 0;
                        margin-bottom: 15px;
                        border-radius: 10px;
                        background: #ffffff;
                        box-shadow: 2.3px 4.5px 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
                        .left-side{
                            float: left;
                            color: #ffffff;
                            min-height: 64px;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            font-size: 17px;
                            padding: 0 26px;
                            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
                            &> img{
                                margin-top: 18px;
                                width: 28px;
                            }

                        }
                        .text{
                            font-size: 14px;
                            width: 75%;
                            float: left;
                            margin-top: 3px;
                            font-weight: normal;
                            padding-left: 14px;
                            line-height: normal;
                            &> span{
                               font-size: 15px;
                               font-weight: bold;
                               color: #448ccb;
                            }
                            &:before{
                                content: '';
                                display: block;
                                position: absolute;
                                top: -2px;
                                left: 61px;
                                border-bottom: 66px solid #ffffff;
                                border-left: 20px solid transparent;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Вводите CSS или меняйте метку. Это не CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Можете регулировать паддингами отступы сверху и снизу или же обернуть 2 блока с текстом в один и задать ему:

```
.имя этого блока {
position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

и обязательно:

```
.rent-of-dedicated-server-backups-list {
position:relative;
}
```

Тогда текст станет *четко* по центру блока, а отступ слева уже сами можете отрегулировать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример на флексах

```
    <div class="wrap">
  <div class="wrap__line">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box__img">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3ga5J8nVeqXu5bNPv4UfU73nlNUNGvbPuTb8em_--FU9vyZL92w" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box__text">
        <div class="text">Блок №1</div>
        <div class="text"><span>Описание первого блока</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap__line">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box__img">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3ga5J8nVeqXu5bNPv4UfU73nlNUNGvbPuTb8em_--FU9vyZL92w" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box__text">
        <div class="text">Блок №2</div>
        <div class="text"><span>Описание второго блока</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap__line">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box__img">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3ga5J8nVeqXu5bNPv4UfU73nlNUNGvbPuTb8em_--FU9vyZL92w" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="box__text">
        <div class="text">Блок №3</div>
        <div class="text"><span>Описание третьего блока</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  &__line {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  &__img {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;

    img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    }  
  }
}

.text {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;

  span {
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}
```